# Get Markers dynamically in Google Map

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a list of Google map addresses in database and i want that if i give the latitude & longitude of one of the address form my list.Than the all the markers comes nearer to this point.and the markers should be from my database list.

For Example :if i have a list of 20 schools with their latitude & longitude and i want the list of all schools nearer to school A may be of around 5 KM.Than all the addresses comes in map which are stored in my database not other schools which are also pins in Google map.

**What i have:
I have a script in which if i passed the latitude & longitude than it gives the list nearer to this point.but the pins comes in the map is gives by Google map and i want that the pins should be from my database.**

Here is the script you can try this at Xampp ,Wampp etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Place Search</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>

    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 600px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        margin-top: 0.6em;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      var map;
      var infowindow;

      function initialize() {
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(22.716498,75.86812);//here you can pass the latitude & longitude.

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: pyrmont,
          zoom: 15
        });

        var request = {
          location: pyrmont,
          radius: 500,
          types: ['store']
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="text">

  </body>
</html>
```

**I Want:
I want the list should be from my database and remember i took the entries in database from Google map API.so i don't need to create the pins they are already a pins address.**

Plz suggest how can i do this.

Comment: You probably want to read this article here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: thnks ducan ..!! useful link for me but still i am troubling. anyway it takes me nearer to my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i found the answer:
I just have to write the query for retrieve records from particular pin(latitude,longitude).

```
SELECT * , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) - RADIANS( $lng ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( $lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM users HAVING distance <25
```

the above query retrieve the all pins which are far at least 25 km from the give latitude & longitude.

Answer (score 0):

On click / select marker event you can pass parameters to 'fetch_results' i.e. schools within 20 Meters radius.

```
var $_METERS = 1000;  // to meters

$this->db->select('`your_school_table`.* CEILING((( acos( sin((' . $options['lat'] . ' * pi() / 180 )) *  sin(( `your_school_table`.`sc_latitude` * pi() / 180 )) + cos((' . $options['lat'] . ' * pi() / 180 )) * cos(( `your_school_table`.`sc_latitude` * pi() / 180 )) * cos(((' . $options['lng'] . ' -  `your_school_table`.`sc_longitude` ) * pi() / 180 )))) * 180 / pi() ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * ' . $this->_METERS . ' ) as distance');
```